# Passing value from DataGridView to DateTimePicker

Tags: vb.net

When I am passing value from DataGridView to a DateTimePicker, I am getting this error

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

and here is my code

```
Dateadd.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(DGVTest(0,DGVTest.SelectedRows(0).Index).Value)
```

Comment: The error message seems clear. In the debugger, check the value of `DGVTest(0,DGVTest.SelectedRows(0).Index).Value`

Comment: What is the format of your datagridview datetime? Show sample date.

Comment: We have no idea where the data comes from or how it is stored, but if it is a DateTime in the DGV it just needs to be cast.  Note that if that is the case, the DGV will enforce that the user can only enter valid dates

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?:

```
Dateadd.value = CDate(DGVTest(0, DGVTest.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).value
```

It looks as if you code is just returning the value of the index of row (0), so just 0?
Do you need to get the date time value from a cell withing the grid view? The code you have written does not do that. In that case try:

```
Dateadd.value = CDate(DGVTest.Rows(0).Cells(0).value)
```

Let me know if this works for you.